# what's the name of the program/app/daemon that "plays" music in rhythmbox when i try to quit it with close button?

Tags: gnome, music, rhythmbox, music-player, gnome-shell-extension

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 with gnome-shell and "mediaplayer-extension" from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/55/.  When i hit the close button on a music player, like rhythmbox 2.9x, it hides somewhere, but it keeps playing music in the background. But if i try to do the same on another distro, when I hit the close button, rhythmbox quits instantly.

The question is: What's the **program/app/daemon's name** that "plays" music in background **even** if i try to quit rhythmbox (or any music player **without** a tray-icon) with "close" button? If i try to remove **that** program, will rhythmbox (or any music player) quit on "close" button? (because i need that)

I know it isn't "mediaplayer-extension" nor "rhythmbox-client", but i can't identify the program. Can somebody help me? Thanks.

(My native language isn't english so i don't know if it's well drafted.)

**edit**
For clarification, what I'm wondering is:
Why does rhythmbox hide on Ubuntu by hitting on "close" button instead of quitting it?

Why does rhythmbox quit on Fedora by hitting on "close" button instead of hiding it?

Is there a program that modifies rhythmbox's behaviour in ubuntu that fedora doesn't have, or viceversa?

**edit 2**

It doesn't only happen in rhythmbox. If i use another music player, like quodlibet or banshee (both ***without*** tray icon), it keeps playing music on Ubuntu, but quits instantly on Fedora when i hit on the same **"close"** button.

Is that (hide-on-close) a normal behaviour that i can **only** find on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

It's still Rhythmbox, but I suspect that you may have a different version of Rhythmbox on the other distros which is why you see different behavior.  There has been some [back](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/5488) and [forthing](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/658590) over the [behavior](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/694860) of Rhythmbox's close button.

But currently, on Ubuntu 12.04, the Rhythmbox close button is simply hiding the player's shell.  The player is still running and playing your tracks.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose (and why you probably installed it) of the GNOME shell extension [Media Player Indicator](https://github.com/eonpatapon/gnome-shell-extensions-mediaplayer) is to control the media players in your system over a indicator applet. This includes starting and stopping the player via the MPRIS D-Bus implementation that Rhythmbox offers. There is a similar implementation in the Unity [Sound Menu/Indicator Sound](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoundMenu).

The way it should operate by design is that whenever you close the window of a media player while it is playing it should **minimize**. The application that plays sound still will be Rhythmbox. In case the player does not play anything it should quit however.

To see if this functionality is also implemented in the Media Player Indicator, stop playback before you are able to terminate Rhythmbox.

Comment: `The way it should operate by design is that whenever you close the window of a media player while it is playing it should minimize.` The cross should always quit an application definitely and never daemonize it. a second button to daemonize application that can be should be created instead

Comment: @Kiwy: you may have entirely misunderstood my answer here. I am not talking about how **I** feel an application should behave, but I just said how it was implemented in the Media Player Indicator. I fully agree with you that this implementation is confusing ;)

Comment: well sorry than, I would cancel my downvote if you edit your answer, just a space would be enough ;)