# How does one properly quit Rythmbox

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, music-player, ux

I use Rythmbox 3.4.4 on Xubuntu 20.10

The only way to quit the application that I can see is the upper right [X]. Which does quit, however the music goes on playing until I manuall kill the `pulseaudio` process, which is neither elegant nor convenient.

The Help says quitting is `Ctl + Q`, which in fact does nothing.

What am I missing ?

Alternatively, what would be another good music player ?

Comment: Did you try Ctrl+Q with the Rhythmbox window focused?

Comment: Well, you can always use Alt+F4.

Comment: Stop the playing before clicking the X

Comment: @NonnyMoose: I did.
schrodigerscatcuriosity: same as above
Jean-Marie:indeed …

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1337038/8822

Answer (score 1):

Try to click the small rythmbox icon in the top of the panel and click Stop & Quit.

[image: Stop & Quit]

If you want another music player then this link may help:

https://www.tecmint.com/best-music-players-for-ubuntu-linux-mint/

UPDATE:
Here are some answers that may help you

[Rhythmbox still plays songs after exit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17134/rhythmbox-still-plays-songs-after-exit)

[Is there a plugin for Rhythmbox to exit on close?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454177/is-there-a-plugin-for-rhythmbox-to-exit-on-close)

Comment: I don't have a "Stop & Quit" item in the panel's menu. Xubuntu's WM is XFCE, what's yours ?

Thanks for the link,