# Show a window again: Rhythmbox is playing music but I can not see the window anywhere

Tags: rhythmbox

I have open rhythmbox, but now it is not in the tasks bar, even if the music is being played.

I have tried `fg process_id` but it doesn't show the window.

Comment: You may be interested in this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/139985/whats-the-name-of-the-program-app-daemon-that-plays-music-in-rhythmbox-when-i and http://askubuntu.com/questions/454177/is-there-a-plugin-for-rhythmbox-to-exit-on-close

Comment: that is usual, because rythmbox is working as a server. in your right top corner there is an indicator for the sound volume, if you click onto it you can select `Rhythmbox` and this will bring it back to foreground.

Answer (score 3):

click the speaker icon the task bar 
then you will see a list of players listed click on rhythmbox